# Spring can not call Rest Endpoint get 404

Tags: java, spring, url, controller

I have setup a service with spring boot but I can't call my rest endpoint.

**CODE:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/route")
@SessionAttributes("session_userId")
public class RoutingController extends BaseController implements WebMvcConfigurer{
```

Endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/web")
    public ModelAndView routeToUserInterfaceServiceWeb(HttpSession session,Device device) {
```

The service runs on port 8000. So when I do in my browser:
"localhost:8000/route/users/web" I expect a any answer of the server. But all I get is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the controller annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/route")
```

Keep the original annotation on the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/route/users/web")
```

`ModelAndView` is a Spring MVC construction.  I would expect a REST service to return a `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: Updated; try again.  You don't say anything about GET or POST.  Don't you need more?